# Counting sequences - a recurrence relation.

Tags: co.combinatorics

Can someone lead me to a method for calculating the number of sequences of length $n$ if the terms of the sequence are chosen (with replacement) from a set with $k$-elements under the condition that all $k$-elements are chosen at least once? It's not my field.

I lead myself to consider the recurrence relation 
$$ R(k,n) = k R(k,n-1) + k R(k-1,n-1) $$
where $R(k,k) = k!, R(k,n) = 0$ if $n \lt k$ and $R(1,n) = 1$ for all $n$, but struggled to close it out. Is there a method for this?

$R(n,k)$ is the number I want, so from my point of view I'm asking one question. From your point of view I'm sure I'm asking two. Many Thanks.

Comment: Because you "asked two", you got answers from two, and those two are twin answers. I see this on MO for the 1st time...

Comment: See also this question [Number of surjections from {1,…,m} into {1,…,n}](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716886/number-of-surjections-from-1-m-into-1-n).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are related to Stirling numbers. These don't have a "closed form".
Your $R(k,n)=k!S(n,k)$ where $S(n,k)$ is the Stirling number of
the second kind as defined at
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind .

Comment: It's funny to see two identical answers.

Comment: See http://oeis.org/A019538.

Answer (score 6):

We have $R(k, n) = k! \cdot S(n, k)$, where $S(n, k)$ is a Stirling number of the second kind: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind